# I am looking to find a sample size that would show a chemical does not change the time of a reaction signifcantly

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics

This is for a clot assay. I have a mean of 39.1 sec, standard deviation of 0.9 sec, and a CV(%) of 2.3, my confidence interval would be 95%. I am looking to calculate the sample size. The equation I have found is

$n = \frac{(Z_{a/2})^2*\sigma^2}{E^2}$

where I do not know how to find E, the margin of error. I also have no population size.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone with

$n = \frac{(Z_\alpha + Z_\beta)^2*\sigma^2}{\Delta^2}$

because I have been told to. No one has shown me how this is derived.